# Elastomer that is durable & oxidation resistant

Tags: material-science, product-engineering, elasticity

I tend to bundle up my folders & small supplies with ordinary rubber bands (polyisoprene). I find that after a few months these rubber bands would deteriorate & need replacing. Faster even when I leave my bundled supplies in the deck of the house where sunlight gets onto it.

So I need rubber bands made of an elastomer that does not age too quickly & have good oxidation resistance (such as against UV). I've found these "EPDM file bands" in Amazon. I was wondering if this is the best type of product for my needs or are there better options?

Answer (score 0):

there are better alternatives, but sourcing them will be a problem.

first is silicone. I do not know of a source for silicone bands. Second is urethane, same comment.

Comment: I don't know about urethane-based rubber. All of them that I've come across with do no stretch as much as polyisoprene rubber bands does.